# How to join variables in csh script

Tags: csh

I am trying to concatenate two variables in a csh script

Here is part of the script

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set encname = _11111k_1920x1080_x264_5200_quicktime_128.mp4

set lowerisrc = `echo $isrc | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`

echo "$lowerisrc$encname"
```

This outputs:

```
_11111k_1920x1080_x264_5200_quicktime_128.mp4
```

The lowerisrc variable should be a value for example "ggttgttgg"

It seems as if the lowerisrc variable is not recognized as a string using the lower function

How do I get the following result as the output?

```
ggttgttgg_11111k_1920x1080_x264_5200_quicktime_128.mp4
```

Comment: Of course I can't resist linking to [this](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes don't nest like that. Change the line that sets `lowerisrc` to:

```
set lowerisrc = "`echo $isrc | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`"
```

With your current code, that line:

```
set lowerisrc = "`echo $isrc | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`"
```

contains 3 double-quoted strings:

```
"`echo $isrc | tr "
" "
"`"
```

and the `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` are probably expanded by the shell as file matching patterns.

**UPDATE:** And now you've changed the code in your question. I just tried  your revised code (with the addition of a line to set the value of `$isrc`), and it works correctly, which makes the question meaningless.

Here's a complete script that works for me:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set isrc = GGttGttGG
set encname = _11111k_1920x1080_x264_5200_quicktime_128.mp4
set lowerisrc = "`echo $isrc | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`"
echo "$lowerisrc$encname"
```

The output is:

```
ggttgttgg_11111k_1920x1080_x264_5200_quicktime_128.mp4
```

Comment: This gives me the same output results.

Comment: I was trying different combinations of the upper lower function. I edited the question with the original values.

Comment: @user1526912: If you change the code in your question, it's very difficult to answer consistently.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu on an EC2 instance and not getting the correct ouput. I would find it hard to believe that this may be environment related.

Comment: @user1526912: Copy-and-paste the script in my answer and run it on your system. What output do you get? The script in your question doesn't set a value for `$isrc`; could that be the problem? (If `$isrc` is a shell variable you set outside the script, it won't be visible in side the script.)

Comment: Thanks Kieth. I tried the same script on Rackspace Linux instance and it works

Comment: @user1526912: EC2 vs. Rackspace *shouldn't* matter. You said the original problem was on EC2. Have you tried my script on EC2?

Comment: What I am saying is that my original script posted  works on a Centos box in Rackspace. I am saying that the problem is environmental.

Comment: @user1526912: I still can't tell where the value of `$isrc` is coming from. Can you update your question with a *complete* and *self-contained* script that illustrates the problem, and show us the output you get in both environments?